# Why does Software use it's own proxy settings?

Tags: linux, proxy, environment-variables

Why does some software on Linux e.g. wget and apt-get/aptitude don't make use of the system variables for proxys?

Is the difference between all the system too large to do that or is it just because it was needed before the war?

Why don't they all just check if the variable is present and not empty and use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Why don't they all just check if the variable is present and not empty and use that?**

[Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Proxies) supports proxies specified in environment variables like `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

So does [apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy)

So does [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) (see ENVIRONMENT section)

So does Lynx

---

See also

- [apt-get doesn't work behind a proxy](https://askubuntu.com/a/424542/257118)